# Recurrence relation with blocks

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

We have a path of size $N$ and $1\times1$ blocks of $4$ colors: *yellow, red, blue and white*. We need to fill the path with blocks but we cannot have $2$ blocks of the same color in a row (we can have $2$ white blocks in a row only, but not $2$ yellow $2$ red or $2$ blue). I need to find the recurrence relation for this problem. (The question is how many different ways do we have to fill the path with these blocks)

How I started:

We can fill the first space with any of the $4$ options - $4f(n-1)$ We can fill the second place for sure with $3$ blocks if the first color was non-white and $4$ blocks if the first color was white. And this is where I am stuck.

$\begin{align}
f(1) &= 4\\
f(2) &= 13\\
\end{align}$

Comment: Are we restricted to $2$ consecutive white blocks or can there be more?

Comment: WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW is valid.
WWWYY is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s one approach. I’ll describe it in some detail, since you can use similar ideas to analyze many similar problems.

Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to fill a path of length $n$, and let $b_n$ be the number of those ways that end in a white block. Suppose that we’ve filled a path of length $n$; in how many ways can we extend it to a path of length $n+1$?

- If the path of length $n$ ends in a white block, we can add a block of any color, so there are $4$ ways to extend it. Since there are $b_n$ paths of length $n$ that end in a white block, this accounts for $4b_n$ paths of length $n+1$.
- If the path of length $n$ ends in a non-white block, we can add a block of any color except the color of the last block, so there are $3$ ways to extend it. There are $a_n-b_n$ paths of length $n$ that end in a non-white block, so this accounts for another $3(a_n-b_n)$ paths of length $n+1$.

These are the only possibilities, so

$$a_{n+1}=4b_n+3(a_n-b_n)=3a_n+b_n\;.$$

But we want to express $a_{n+1}$ only in terms of $a_n,a_{n-1}$, etc., so we have to get rid of $b_n$ somehow. One way is to find a companion recurrence for $b_{n+1}$. How many paths of length $n+1$ ending in a white block did we just create? That’s easy: *every* path of length $n$ can be extended by a white block, so $b_{n+1}=a_n$. Of course that means that $b_n=a_{n-1}$, and hence

$$a_{n+1}=3a_n+a_{n-1}$$

or, if you prefer,

$$a_n=3a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}\;.$$

Now you just need two initial values to get the recurrence off the ground. There is one way to fill the path of length $0$ — use no blocks! — and as you say, there are $4$ ways to fill a path of length $1$, so $a_0=1$ and $a_1=4$.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.
I ended up with 4f(n-1)+3f(n-2) and tried to test it however I kept getting larger values than expected. Do you have any idea which combinations I ended up counting as extra? (I expected to get lesser resutls than the expected value)

Comment: @Hydroxis: I’d have to think about it, but at first glance it appears that your first term includes paths ending in two blocks of the same non-white color, and your second includes some of the paths counted in the first term.

Comment: The logic I used was the one I described in the original post. We can start with any of the colors and fill the rest in n-1 ways.
I'll numerate colors as 1 2 3 4.
For the next slot we have at least 3 choices (1 | 2 or 3 or 4, 2 | 1 or 3 or 4, 3 | 1 or 2 or 4, 4 | 1 or 2 or 3) and I thought I'd need to include the choices where I didn't include adjacent 1 (1 = white)

Comment: @Hydroxis: You can make that kind of argument work. It’s true that no matter how a path of length $n$ ends, there are at least $3$ ways to extend it to a path of length $n+1$; that accounts for $3a_n$ paths of length $n+1$. To that you have to add the number of paths of length $n$ that can be extended in a fourth way. These are the ones that end in white, and since every path of length $n-1$ can be extended with white, there are $a_{n-1}$ of them. Thus, $a_{n+1}=3a_n+a_{n-1}$ or, shifting the indices, $a_n=3a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$.

Comment: And what happens to the first part? (4 choices to fill first slot?)

Comment: @Hydroxis: I’ve been discussing how you can find the recurrence, which tells you what $a_n$ is in terms of earlier values; getting the initial value(s) is a separate issue altogether. It sounds now as if you got in trouble by trying to incorporate the initial value(s) into your analysis of the recurrence; that’s definitely a mistake.